# Android - Viewpager - Getting the ItemId of a list array item

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to get the itemid for an item within a list array that I have created.

I'm using a view pager and pager adapter to show the data for each record which I can swipe to the next record. I understand that my viewpager adapter creates 3 pages when first accessed so that when I pass the id back to my activity it is the next record or previous record if swiping right. As that is the id of the record that was added last

```
GamesDetail.idforgame = (nesListItems.getItemId());
```

I have tried accessing the array like I do on pages that use a list view to display the names of the records but I can't work out how to implement this when not using an onclick listener.

```
public void editgame(){
    pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    nesListItems = (NesItems) arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    idforgame = nesListItems.getItemId();
    Log.d("Pixo", "Value: " + idforgame);
    Intent intent = new Intent(GamesDetail.this, EditOwnedGame.class);//opens a new screen when the shopping list is clicked
    intent.putExtra("editgameid", idforgame);
    startActivity(intent);//start the new screen
}
```

I'm using a menu to edit various parts of each record, so need an easy way to get the item id for the currently shown record.That I can use for the other editing functions.

This is my pager adapter

```
public class NesPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context; //sets up a variable as context
ArrayList<NesItems> nesList; //sets up  an array called shoppingList
String gameimage, synop, gen, subgen, pub, dev, gname, img, theyear;
int owned, carttrue, boxtrue, manualtrue, gameid, editgameid, pos, idforgame;

public NesPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NesItems> list) {
    this.context = context;//sets up the context for the class
    nesList = list; //sets up a variable as a list
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return nesList.size();
} //returns the number of items in the array

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ScrollView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    NesItems nesListItems = nesList.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //sets up the layout inflater
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_games_detail, null); //use the layout to diaplay the array data

    TextView gamename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGameName);
    ImageView cover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgGameCover);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGenre);
    TextView subgenre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSubgenre);
    TextView publisher = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblPublisher);
    TextView developer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblDeveloper);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblYear);
    ImageView cart = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCart);
    ImageView box = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBox);
    ImageView manual = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgManual);
    TextView synopsis = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSynopsis);
    synopsis.setText(nesListItems.getSynopsis());
    publisher.setText(nesListItems.getPublisher());
    genre.setText(nesListItems.getGenre());
    subgenre.setText(nesListItems.getSubgenre());
    gamename.setText(nesListItems.getName()); //sets the textview name with data from name
    developer.setText(nesListItems.getDeveloper());
    year.setText(nesListItems.getYear());
    Log.d("Pixo", "Item id: " + idforgame);
    gameimage = nesListItems.getImage();
    owned = nesListItems.getOwned();
    carttrue = nesListItems.getCart();
    boxtrue = nesListItems.getBox();
    manualtrue = nesListItems.getManual();
    int coverid=context.getResources().getIdentifier(gameimage, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    cover.setImageResource(coverid);

    if(owned == 1){
        if(carttrue == 1){
            cart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{}
        if(boxtrue == 1){
            box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{}
        if(manualtrue == 1){
            manual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else{}
    }

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(convertView);
    //nesListItems = nesList.get(pos);
    GamesDetail.idforgame = (nesListItems.getItemId());
    Log.d("Pixo","Current position: " + position + " game id: " + idforgame);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ScrollView) object);

}
```

}

Comment: You will have to post core code, especially where arg0 is being held.

Comment: I'm not using arg0 at the moment its what I'm trying to make use of, simlilar to how it gets used when you have an onclicklistener, I can't figure out how to get the adpater view like is used with one

Comment: Found out I can implement

'public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container,
                               int position,
                               Object object)'

and pass the id back to the activity that has the code for setting up the arraylist